# Why this code cant make overlay item appear in my current location 

Tags: android

Hey i want to add an image to appear in my current location and here is my code i added overlay items but i want to add method or something like this to make an overlay item appear in my current location , i added the bmp to add the item in my curent location please can any one check it out !!!! so Please why it cant appear in my current location ?? why it cant appear the overlay item in my current location  Despite they appear in the position i enter !!!

```
enter code here
package tryanabtry.opa;
 import java.util.List;

 import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
     import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
  import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
   import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
 import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;


    public class tryanabtry extends MapActivity

      {
private MapView mapView;
private MapController mc;

    int error=100;
GeoPoint p, p2, p3, p4;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable, drawable2 , drawable3, drawable4;
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay, itemizedOverlay2 , itemizedOverlay3,        itemizedOverlay4;

            /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        @Override

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

  {
   try{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.main);


    /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

      LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

                mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
             mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    // enable Street view by default
     mapView.setStreetView(true);


      mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

         mc = mapView.getController();

         mc.setZoom(12); 
         addOverLays();
                  }
             catch(Exception e){
   Log.d("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",e.getMessage());
           }

            }
          public void addOverLays(){
         String [] coordinates = {"31.216487288475037","29.932637214660645"  ,"30.084123015403748", "51.5002" , "-0.1262","31.337149143218994"};
             double lat = 29.98739718380868,lat2 =  29.98763859272003,lat3=29.987574219703674,lat4=29.98718498160553;
             double log = 31.442527770886084, 
              log2 = 31.44235074520111,
             log3=31.44225418567575,log4=31.442527770996094;

   p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (log * 1E6));
    p2 = new GeoPoint( (int) (lat2 * 1e6), (int) (log2 * 1e6));
   p3=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat3 * 1e6), (int) (log3 * 1e6));
   p4=new GeoPoint( (int) (lat4 * 1e6), (int) (log4 * 1e6));


     mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vitblue);
    drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballon);
   drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blackaaaaa);
    drawable4 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vitblue);

   itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
   itemizedOverlay2 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable2,this);        
   itemizedOverlay3 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable3,this);    
   itemizedOverlay4 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable4,this);    
   OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Cairo", " over1");
   OverlayItem over2 = new OverlayItem(p2, "ulm", "over2");
   OverlayItem over3 = new OverlayItem(p3, "offff", "over3");
   OverlayItem over4 = new OverlayItem(p4, "offff", "over4");

  itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

   itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(over2);
   mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);

   itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(over3);
  mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3);

  itemizedOverlay4.addOverlay(over4);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay4);
      mc.setZoom(17); 
        mc.animateTo(p4);

          }
```

/* Class My Location Listener */

```
        public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

           {

       @Override

             public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

           {





GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(    (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
        (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));



        String Text = "My current location is: " +

        "Latitud ="+ loc.getLatitude() +

             "Longitud =" + loc.getLongitude();



             Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

                 Text,

               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////WHAT I ADDED 
drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blackaaaaa);
// itemizedOverlay3 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable3,this);
  OverlayItem over3 = new OverlayItem(point, "offff", "over3");
itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(over3);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//// THE LINE NEW HELLOITEMIZEDOVERLAY !! GET AN ERROR !! ANY SOLUTION 

              mc.animateTo(point);

if (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6>=p.getLatitudeE6()-error&&loc.getLongitude() * 1E6 < p.getLatitudeE6()+error)
     mapView.getOverlays().remove(itemizedOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();


///////////////////////////////
class MapOverlay extends Overlay
{
    private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

    public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
    }

public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
        return pointToDraw;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

        // convert point to pixels
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

        // add marker
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null); // 24 is the height of image        
        return true;
    }
} 

                    }


                private Resources getResources() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
                   }


             private void DoubletoString(double latitude) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


             public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

              {

      Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

        "Gps Disabled",

         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

               }


         public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

                 {

           Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

              "Gps Enabled",

            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  }


                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

                      {


                      }

                        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
                  return false;
                          }

                      }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */


                     @Override
                  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return false;
                            }


                               }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
enter code here

05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting    due to uncaught exception
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at   tryanabtry.opa.tryanabtry$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(tryanabtry.java:182)
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:181)
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:114)
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:130)
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
 05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
 05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
  05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should try to improve your coding style. Eclipse supports auto formatting which produces at least a readable code style. What you provided here is barely readable... If you got an error, post the error message from you LogCat view in eclipse... and, ehm, work on your language, quite hard so read such sentences

Comment: drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blackaaaaa);

//   itemizedOverlay3 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable3,this);

OverlayItem over3 = new OverlayItem(point, "offff", "over3");

 itemizedOverlay3.addOverlay(over3);

 mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay3); !!

 but helloitemizedoverlay get an error  please i neeed a help please

Comment: The constructor HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable, tryanabtry.MyLocationListener) is undefined and when i add the constructur in the  public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable drawable3,
   MyLocationListener myLocationListener) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 error in it its underline with red line

Comment: Go step by step. If you created the constructor and you got an error there, find out what the error is and try to fix it. Step by step...

Comment: Implicit super constructor ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

Comment: you must call super(...) in that constructor. Thats basic java knowledge. If you get coding issues (inside eclipse), you should try to google that and learn the reason why they appear.

Comment: i done supper sure but if force close

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435): java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at tryanabtry.opa.tryanabtry$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(tryanabtry.java:182)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:181)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:114)

Comment: 05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:130)
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: 05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-08 17:12:06.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1435):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: add that to your question,I can't read a thing here in the comments...

Answer (score 0):

Hey maybe you want to try that https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons and modify it to show your images. I think this works great if you want to show additional content to a location.