# point condition to be remove

Tags: android

If I 'm using GPS and adding some Over lay items in the map and i want to play a game when ever my current location is == to the over lay item then remove this item the problem is due to the gps inaccuracy i want to make a margin error around the over lay item so what i did is
Since the P is the geo point of the overlay item

```
enter code here
   int error =10 ;
if (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6>=p.getLatitudeE6()-error&&loc.getLongitude() * 1E6 < p.getLatitudeE6()+error)
 mapView.getOverlays().remove(itemizedOverlay);
  mapView.invalidate();
```

so the question now is this if condition is true or what ??

Answer (score 0):

Use `LocationManager.addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent)`.  The radius will be the distance you are to the POI.

Comment: can u please tell me if its a method format because it give error telling put it as constructor or add void  !! and again what this method really do and how it will help me ???

Comment: You need to instantiate a `LocationManager` which you should have already done.  The method will fire off a pending intent which you can use to start a new `Activity`.

Comment: why do i need it i dis need this method i just want to check if my if condition is right or what ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922246/why-this-code-cant-make-overlay-item-appear-in-my-current-location

Comment: @uouo:  look at http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html.  it is a specific maps api class for showing your location.

Comment: i did it and i show my current location i use gps but the problem that i can not add specific overlay in my location despite i add it in other location i enter

Comment: @uouo:  sorry the link i meant was http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html for the MyLocationOverlay class.  i am not sure what you mean.  do you want a custom icon showing your current location?  is that the problem?